# Float object error when trying list operations

Tags: python

I was basically trying to recreate some algorithm. An user is supposed to enter values from the keyboard and they get converted into a list. After that I wanted to add the two smallest value from list and then repeat until I get the value of 1. But, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ********* line 13, in <module>
    while n[:1] != 1.0:
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

This is my code:

```
a = input("Enter values: \n")
n = list(map(float, a.split(' '))) 
OK = 1
if OK:
    while n[:1] != 1.0:
        n = sorted(n)
        print(n)
        n[1] = n[0] + n[1]
        n = n.pop(0)
print(n)
```

Comment: how do you get value of `1` if you add them together? What if user input is "1 2 3"? Can you provide example I/O?

Comment: I didn't post full code :D In that case if OK becomes 0, algorithm ends.

Comment: `n = n.pop(0)` After this line of code, `n` is a single float and is no longer a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that it's printing `n` once?

In your second last line you do `n = n.pop(0)` which means that `n`, which was previously a `list` is now a `float`. And you can't call `n[:1]` if `n` is a float.

I'm not 100% what you're trying to achieve, but try this:

```
a = input("Enter values: \n")
x = list(map(float, a.split(' '))) 
OK = 1
if OK:
    n = x.pop(0)
    while x and n != 1.0:
        x = sorted(x)
        print(x)
        x[1] = x[0] + x[1]
        n = x.pop(0)
print(x)
```

Comment: There are either some bad pop examples on the internet or maybe I got wrong how pop works, but thank you!

Comment: Both are possible. When you `pop` an element from a list, the the element is returned, and the list is modified in place. So if I did `foo = [1, 2, 3]` and then `bar = foo.pop(0)` then `bar` would be `1` and `foo` would be `[2, 3]`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you probably want to use `<` for your condition instead of an exact `!=` check since you're dealing with imprecise floats. Secondly, you keep changing the type of `n` between a list and a float (by assiging it the value of `pop`). Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
a = input("Enter values: \n")
n = list(map(float, a.split(' ')))
OK = 1
if OK:
    while n[0] < 1.0:          # Access the first element with [0] not by slicing with [:1]
        n = sorted(n)
        print(n)
        n[1] = n[0] + n[1]
        n.pop(0)               # Here don't assign this result back to n
print(n)
```

I won't address the case where the values entered are greater than 1 as mentioned by the others and I'll trust that you're handling it properly in the rest of your code

Here's a sample run:

```
Enter values:
0.2 0.1 0.4 0.6 0.4 0.7

[OUTPUT]
[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7]
[0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7]
[0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7000000000000001]
[1.0, 0.7, 0.7000000000000001]
```